# Get localStorage data in nuxt layout function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have such a problem: I need to get localStorage data before nuxt layout is loaded in `pages/index.vue`

`/pages/index.vue`

```html
<script>
export default {
  layout (context) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('AUTH_TOKEN')){
      this.$store.dispatch('changeAuthStatus', {
        authStatus: true,
        accessToken: localStorage.getItem('AUTH_TOKEN'),
        profileData: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('PROFILE_DATA'))
      }).then(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch('changeLoadedStatus', {
          isLoaded: true
        })
      })
    }
    else {
      this.$router.push('/auth')
    }
  }
</script>
```

The error when the page is loaded: `localStorage is not defined`

Maybe I can get localStorage data using context? Or maybe you can suggest to me any package so I can use it in the layout function?

Comment: Btw, you're using `layout` here? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-layout Didn't you mean `middleware()`? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-middleware#anonymous-middleware

Comment: Yes, I use `layout`, I need to get the profileData from localStorage to choose what layout will be loaded next

Comment: Also, prefer using the `async/await` syntax rather than `.then`. It's usually recommended.

Comment: I don't know if it helps you or not, but I mostly use universal storage for setting and retrieving tokens, using the $storage.setUniversal() and $storage.getUniversal() methods.
https://github.com/nuxt-community/universal-storage-module

Comment: @AmirhosseinShahbazi feels like a bazooka, but nice to see that those kind of solutions do exist. You should probably post this as an answer so that it could get accepted and upvoted by OP!

Comment: Yes. As I said, I removed all token checkers to middleware, so my layout() has only 2 conditions that choose what layout will be displayed. So the mix of two answers helped me to solve my promlem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

I just installed [nuxt-universal-storage module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/universal-storage-module), that [Amirhossein Shahbazi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13108482/amirhossein-shahbazi) suggested. So I have just done this:

/pages/index.vue:

```html
<script>
export default {
middleware: ['auth'],
  layout (context) {
    let currentRole = context.app.$storage.getUniversal('PROFILE_DATA')
    console.log(currentRole)
    let currentLayout = 'default'
    let defaultRoles = ['customer_support_manager', 'checker', 'storekeeper']
    let tabletRoles = ['deputy_cutting_shop']
    if (defaultRoles.includes(currentRole.role)) {
      currentLayout = 'default'
    }
    else if (tabletRoles.includes(currentRole.role)) {
      currentLayout = 'tablet'
    }
    return currentLayout
}
</script>
```

/middleware/auth.js:

```
export default function ({ redirect, app, store }) {
    // some token checkers for existing, for 401 error and for their validity
}
```

Comment: So, you're probably using cookies here at some point. Glad that this solution works, meanwhile I'm still not sure why all of this code is in a `layout()`, it is not it's purpose. Do you render a `'blog'` string or alike at the end? If not, this one should probably be a middleware, especially looking at the `$router.push`.

Comment: Yes, of course, I return the string at the end. I just check what role now is Vuex state and then choose what layout will be rendered :) Thank you for the help. So I moved the extra code to the middleware, and now my layout only has some `if`s, where I choose what string I will return in the end

Comment: I'd still stuck with having a dynamic layout rather than dynamically changing layouts. You could make conditional in your layout. At least, I do prefer this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, Nuxt is the SSR solution for Vue (same as Next for React), right?

If so, you don't have access to the localStorage. Server Side is not running in your browser!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of code works fine

```html
<script>
export default {
  layout({ store }) {
    if (process.client) {
      console.log('localStorage?', localStorage.getItem('myCat'))
      console.log('store?', store)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Because `localStorage` is not available on the server.

Try to use `localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom')`, move to your page and see how it displays the `localStorage` and the store (don't forget to use [the context](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/context-helpers) since `this` is not available here).

Comment: The code inside this condition does not run

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting to run there beyond a `return 'blog'` or alike inside of `layout()`.

Comment: I need to define the user role in localStorage to choose what layout will be loaded next

Comment: I don't know why, but the code inside process.client condition doesn't work when I reload the page, but it works when the component is rerendered

Comment: Maybe I can check localStorage inside `middleware`, push the data to Vuex, if localStorage is not empty. And then inside layout check Vuex state? Or it will not work in that way?

Comment: I guess that it depends of your `target` and `ssr` values. A Github repo could be nice to debug it more in depth. Just to be clear, `layout()` is only supposed to return a string for the layout that you want to use. So `$router.push` is a no-go in it. Middleware is probably the way to go here indeed. Also, I don't know if you cannot make your layout dynamic depending of Vuex, rather than relying on modifying `layout()` itself. Also, I checked and it looks like `layout()` is called before `middleware()`. So rather than relying on some hacky solution, I recommend to make the layout adaptive @10k

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cookie-universal-nuxt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt)

After login you can set "AUTH_TOKEN" as cookie instead of localStorage

```
window.$cookies.set('AUTH_TOKEN', token)
```

and you can access it in layout function as

```
layout (context) {
     let token=context.app.$cookies.get('AUTH_TOKEN')
}
```